# Using passthru() to download file results in broken/modified file

Tags: php, download, yii2, header, passthru

I have an PHP Yii2 webapplication, which runs an command line script using `passthru()`. The `passthru()` result should passed into an downloaded file, so that the user can download the output of `passthru()`.

Example:

If I execute the following command line:

```
$ /bin/cat /PATH/pic.jpg > output.jpg
```

...I get an file `output.jpg`, which is identical to `pic.jpg` (same md5 checksum)

But I need to execute this mechanism in an web application:

If I doing the same using `passthru()` in order to send the file to the users browser:

```
            header("Cache-Control: private");
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.jpg");
            passthru ('/bin/cat /PATH/pic.jpg');
```

....than I get an `download.jpg` which is not the same like `pic.jpg`
I this example-case `download.jpg` is 1126 bytes smaller (picture size is around 13MBytes) and the picture can not be opend in some picture viewer.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using `readfile()` here?

Comment: @rob006  This is only an example to simplify/show the problem. In "reallife" `pic.jpg` does not exist an `passthru()` is calling an executable, which generates the binary stuff, which should be send to the user, which see the download in the browser.